# how to scrape data from web page through it's <script> tags in the html source. (PHP)

Tags: php, web-scraping, screen-scraping, domdocument

I want to retrieve some data items from a web page.

Link of webpage:

http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_results.do

Data items which i want to retrieve.

- $StorePhone
- $PharmacyPhone
- $OpenHours
- $PharmacyHours

I tried alot  but i could not do it, because there are neither ids or specific class assigned to the tags, and there is no hierarchy of tags to fetch the data against each heading.

if you see the html source of above page, then there are already data items available in the form of variables inside `<script>` tag , can anyone tell me how to retrieve these data items against each store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you'll have to use a regex for this, though it isn't perfect.

```
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.walmart.com/storeLocator/ca_storefinder_results.do?serviceName=&rx_title=com.wm.www.apps.storelocator.page.serviceLink.title.default&rx_dest=%2Findex.gsp&sfsearch_single_line_address=K6T');
preg_match_all('/stores\[(\d+)\] \= \{/s', $contents, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $index) {
    preg_match('/stores\[' . $index . '\] \= \{(.*?)\}\;/s', $contents, $matches);
    preg_match_all('/\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\' \: ([^\,]*?)\,/s', $matches [1], $matches);
    $c = count ($matches [1]);
    for ($i=0; $i<$c; $i++) {
        $results [$matches [1] [$i]] = trim($matches [2] [$i], "\'");
    }
    print_r ($results);
}
```

Displays this:

```
Array
(
    [fullName] => Ogdensburg Walmart Store #2092
    [street1] => 3000 Ford Street Ext
    [city] => Ogdensburg
    [state] => NY
    [zipcode] => 13669
    [phone] => (315) 394-8990
    [latitude] => 44.7083
    [longitude] => -75.4564
    [storeName] => Walmart
    [storeTypeId] => 2
    [storeId] => 2092
    [distance] => 22.01 miles
    [directionsLink] => directionsLink
    [directionsAvailable] => directionsAvailable
    [directionsMessage] => directionsMessage
    [hasOpen24HoursService] => false
    [open24hrsMessage] => open24hrsMessage
    [hoursWeekDays] => hoursWeekDays
    [hoursSaturday] => hoursSaturday
    [hoursSunday] => hoursSunday
    [weekDays] => storeWeekDays
    [weekEndSaturday] => storeSaturday
    [weekEndSunday] => storeSunday
    [storeInfoDays] => storeInfoDays
    [storeInfoHours] => storeInfoHours
    [moreDetailsLink] => moreDetailsLink
    [openingSoon] => false
    [recentlyOpen] => false
    [siteToStoreAvailable] => true
    [hasStoreEvent] => true
    [eventLink] => http://localad.walmart.com/walmart/new_user_entry.aspx?storeref=2092&forceview=y
)
```

If you want to keep the single quotes (`'`), remove the trim() function.

Comment: Awesome Jeroen!!!
Thanks you so much :)

What i will have to do if need to retrieve information of all stores.   (number of stores varies depending on the search result against zip code. ).

Comment: It's a perfect answer of my question.... Can you please elaborate it, what if i need to store information of all stores......?   can you please edit your code to make it generic for stores[n]..............................................  the storeHours, storeDays variables don't have value as in the website. how can i get the values of hours instead of variable name.

Comment: Added explanation on how to do that

Comment: number of stores varies on the basis of input value of zip code in the url.  so i don't have idea whether there is only one stores or 20 stores.

Comment: Try to find out how to do that yourself, I'm not your personal code monkey ;)

Comment: Can you come online at the [chatroom I added you to](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12067/room-for-jeroen-and-wqs)?

Answer (score 4):

classic scraping will give you a hard time with such a page. You would need to fetch the content of the url and then regex your way out to extract the elements of the `stores` array.

If you have some time to learn some new technologies, i would recommend looking into [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

This headless browser will behave just like a browser and execute javascript.

When opening a console, you will see that the `stores` array is a global variable so it will be easy with phantomJS to read the content of this array.

example of a phantomJS script :

```
var url = "your url";
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open(url, function (status) {
   var stores = page.evaluate(function () {
       return window.stores;
   });
   console.log(stores[0]);
});
```

Comment: I must say this is a nice alternative to using regex, I hadn't thought of this!

Comment: Thanks Jerome WAGNER!
It looks nice and comfortable to use. i'll love to learn it :)         
--------  for now i would try to use Jeroen's technique for the quick solution of my problem..